# Extract all text from sub-element of XML tree in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to extract the  section of government bill data, such as this https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/113/bills/sconres/sconres14/text-versions/is/document.xml. I only want the text from the  section, but can't figure how how to navigate to it using python's xml.etree.ElementTree; the equivalent javascript would be something like getElementbyTagName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you can use `findall()` passing [XPath expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) string as parameter, to find elements with certain criteria. So, for simple element names (those that doesn't contain prefix), the equivalent of Javascript's `getElementbyTagName("elementName")` in `ElementTree` would be `findall(".//tagName")`.